# NullReferenceException after accessing datatable added to dataset

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, dataset

So basically, I have a dataset which contains several datatables, from which columns are removed in my program.
At some point I want to reset my datatable so that all changes to the columns are gone.

Because I can't just create a new instance of that datatable in my dataset, I do this:

```cs
this._dsTest = new DsTest();

//Removing/Adding the first datatable
this._dsTest.Tables.Remove(this._dsTest.TestTable);
this._dsTest.Tables.Add(new DsTest.TestTableDataTable());

//Removing/Adding the second datatable
this._dsTest.Tables.Remove(this._dsTest.ReloadTable);
this._dsTest.Tables.Add(new DsTest.ReloadTableDataTable());
```

However, if I try to access the second datatable, I receive a NullReferenceException, telling me that the second dataTable is null.

What I don't understand is:
If I would add another table to my dataset, that third table would throw the NullReferenceException once I try to access it, and the second one would work without any problems.

Is there anything I am missing that would explain this behaviour?

**Update:**

This is the code I am using to access the datatables:

```cs
this._dsTest.TestTable.AddTestTableRow("Test", 1);
this._dsTest.ReloadTable.AddReloadTableRow(1, "Reload", 1); //This throws the exception
```

Comment: How do you access this second table in the code which gives you an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found the answer to my problem.

The reason that I received the NullReferenceException when I tried to do

```
this._dsTest.ReloadTable.AddReloadTableRow(1, "Reload", 1)
```

was, that the datatable that I added to the dataset was working perfectly fine, but the public property of that datatable  (`this._dsTest.ReloadTable`)
was not set to the datatable I had juts added.

So the solution for this is to simply do this:

```
this._dsTest.InitVars();
```

After that, accessing the DataTable works without a problem.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you made any changes to your dataset / datatable you should use AcceptChanges method.

For example :

```
this._dsTest = new DsTest();    
//Removing/Adding the first datatable
this._dsTest.Tables.Remove(this._dsTest.TestTable);
this._dsTest.AcceptChanges();
this._dsTest.Tables.Add(new DsTest.TestTableDataTable());
this._dsTest.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect whatsoever. I am still receiving a NullReferenceException when I try to use the second table.